# JsonPropertyName is ignored when the data is serialized

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add a property serialization name, but no one of the solutions I've tried seems to work, when the JSON send `short_name` I always get null value, (if the request is changed to `shortName` all works fine).

I've tried to use both `[JsonPropertyName("short_name")]` and `[JsonProperty("short_name")]`

But none worked.

Here is the complete class:

```
public class ProductPayload
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "short_name")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public int Vat { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public Family Family { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> ActivePrinters { get; set; }
    public List<Pricing> Pricing { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Which is then expected from a Controller like this:

```
[HttpPost("products")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ReceiveProducts([FromBody] List<ProductPayload> payload)
{
    await _payloadRepository.InsertProducts(payload);
    return Ok();
}
```

The project is in .NET 6

```
The JSON:

[
    {
        "id": "ABC123",
        "short_name": "Descrizione tasto",
        "name": "Descrizione estesa",
        "unitOfMeasure": "PZ",
        "vat": 10,
        "price": 12.9,
        "purchasePrice": 4.85,
        "category": {
            "id": "5fc98b530536fc0011d7f9a2",
            "name": "TEST"
        },
        "group": {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "Reparto cassa"
        },
        "department": {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "Reparto"
        },
        "family": {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "Famiglia"
        },
        "activePrinters": {
            "1": [
                1,
                3
            ],
            "2": []
        },
        "pricing": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "price": 11.9
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "price": 10.8
            }
        ],
        "background": "#000000",
        "color": "#ffffff"
    }
]
```

Startup.cs:

public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        RegisterScopedServices(services);

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(hostName => true);
                });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "https://example.com",
                ValidAudience = "https://example.com",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TEST")),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
            };
        });

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { 
                Title = "API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "API Documentation."
            });


            var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    private void RegisterScopedServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<DB>();
        services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
        ...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwaggerAuthorized();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
        });

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the json that is send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by removing Newtonsoft.Json from my application, probably it was causing some conflicts and no one of the serialization annotations was working.

Answer (score 1):

I am going out on a limb here, but i suspect the controller/backend of your project is using the System.Text.Json serializer, which doesn't understand Newtonsoft.Json attribute annotations like `[JsonProperty]`.

Try using the equivalent System.Text.Json attribute `[JsonPropertyName]`:

```
    [JsonPropertyName("short_name")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
```

and see whether this improves your situation.

Comment: Hi Jason, I've yet tried it as you can check-out from my question, but it ignores the `JsonPropertyName` , seems like I need to add the serializer in `Startup.cs` maybe?